# Why am I getting TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, types, python-3.x, int

I'm trying to execute this example Python script that I found in *Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science* by John Zelle:

```
# File: chaos.py
# A simple program illustrating chatic behavior

def main():
    print("This program illustrates a chaotic function")
    x = input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")
    for i in range(10):
        x = 3.9 * x * (1 - x)
        print(x)

main()
```

... but for some reason, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\chaos.py", line 11, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\...\chaos.py", line 8, in main
    x = 3.9 * x * (1 - x)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I have no idea how to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: what version of python are you using? this works perfectly over here in 2.7. it even works when i enter really really jank numbers... Ok i got it to do the error, but only after i tried entering a string...... When it says "Enter a number between 0 and 1:" what are you typing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` always returns a string:

```
>>> type(input(":"))
:a
<class 'str'>
>>> type(input(":"))
:1
<class 'str'>
>>>
```

Convert the input to a float:

```
x = float(input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: "))
```

Comment: Not an int. It's between 0 and 1.

Comment: @user2357112 - Good catch.  Don't know how I missed that.

Comment: `>>> x = input()
3
>>> x
3
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>` input() returns whatever type you put into it

Comment: @TehTris - The OP is using Python 3.x.  Thus, my code is for 3.x.

Comment: @iCodez then i take away that -1 :), OP never answered when i asked

Comment: in 2.7 `print(x)` works and so does `print x` .... maybe im missing something......

Answer (score 4):

`input()` by default returns a string. You would have to cast it to `float` before using it.

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#input) (Looks like you are using Python 3.x)

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

The culprit is:

```
x = input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")
```

Try

```
x = input("Enter a number between 0 and 1: ")
x = float(x)
```